# Sqlite3 to retrieve earliest and latest records for a particular ID and DEPT

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I retrieve the first and the last updated record from the table group by ID where the latest updated record is by DEPT Sales.

```
 ID     DEPT        DATETIME         
=====================================     
1       Account  2016:09:01 14:11:44 
1       Account  2016:09:01 15:12:50 
1       Account  2016:09:01 16:11:33 
1       Sales    2016:09:01 18:19:34 
1       Sales    2016:09:01 18:28:50 
1       Sales    2016:09:01 18:35:22     
2       HR       2016:09:01 18:25:50  
2       Sales    2016:09:01 18:26:10  
2       Sales    2016:09:01 18:34:44     
3       HR       2016:09:01 18:27:50  
3       Sales    2016:09:01 18:28:40  
3       Sales    2016:09:01 18:35:22      
4       HR       2016:09:01 18:27:50  
4       Sales    2016:09:01 18:28:40  
4       Admin    2016:09:01 18:35:22
```

***Expected output***

```
 ID     DEPT        DATETIME         
=====================================     
1       Account  2016:09:01 14:11:44 
1       Sales    2016:09:01 18:35:22 
2       HR      2016:09:01 18:25:50  
2       Sales   2016:09:01 18:34:44  
3       HR      2016:09:01 18:27:50  
3       Sales   2016:09:01 18:35:22
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select id, min(datetime) as mindt, max(datetime) as maxdt
      from t
      group by id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id and
        t.datetime in (tt.mindt, tt.maxdt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there can be more then 2 departments for an id, and min must be from all but 'Sales' DEPT, try

```
select id 
      ,(select min(DEPT)
        from table t2 
        where t2.id = t.id and t2.datetime = t.mindt) as DEPT
      ,mindt as datetime
from (
    select id, min(datetime) as mindt
    from table 
    where DEPT !='Sales'
    group by id) t
UNION ALL
select id, DEPT, max(datetime) 
from table 
where DEPT ='Sales'
group by id, DEPT
```